# Contracts do not compile with zksync-solc. Their ABI and bytecode seem to be printed as an error

Tags: compilation, solidity, hardhat

I am pretty new to development and asking questions on stackoverflow, so if there is something else I could provide, please tell me in comments!

I have installed docker, @matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc, @matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy, zksync-web3, hardhat, @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable, @openzeppelin/contracts and everything else.

A simple contract that stores uint and deploys ERC20 contract compiles fine, but the project I am working on does not compile and instead prints a very long error that seem to be ABIs and bytecodes of every contract that is used in the project.

Here is the beginning of the error:

```
Error in plugin @matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc: {"contracts":{"@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967Proxy.sol":{"ERC1967Proxy":{"abi":[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_logic","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"previousAdmin","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"newAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"AdminChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"beacon","type":"address"}],"name":"BeaconUpgraded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"implementation","type":"address"}],"name":"Upgraded","type":"event"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}],"evm":{"legacyAssembly":null,"bytecode":{"object":"0c0000040004000000010000000000000000ffffffffffffffff0000000000000c000004000400000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000e000000000200000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a020004000800000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000010001000000001000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000c00001000100
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know at what point the code stops, like the specific line/method/function that is causing the contract to fail at compile?

Another option would be to join their discord and drop in on the dev chat [here](https://discord.gg/nMaPGrDDwk). They've been incredibly helpful and are patient with new devs.